# python list columns split

Tags: python, list, listview, interpolation

Could anyone help me please? It is complicated question but i will try explain it. I need interpolate two values Depths(Z) to Speed(v) for all data

```
x= [55,55,55,,44,44,44,,33,33,33,] (coordinates)
z =[10,5,0,10,7,0,10,9,0]  (depths)
v= [20,21,22=,23,24,25,26,27,28] (speed)
```

And result

```
DEPTHS   SPEED(55)        SPEED(44)              SPEED(33)     
10       20              23                      26
6        21.5(interp)    24.5(interp)            27.5 (interp)
0        22              25                      28
```

What I did:

```
import numpy as np
    X_list=[55,55,55,44,44,44,33,33,33] 
    Z_list=[10,5,0,10,7,0 10,9,0]
    V_list=[20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28]
    x = np.linspace(min(Z_list),max(Z_list),num = 3) #(Find min and max values in  all list, and put step
    d=np.interp(x, Z_list, V_list) # interpolation for interesting depths
    zipped = list(zip(x,d))
    print (*zipped, sep="\n")
```

And actually I got  information from first cordinate

```
 DEPTHS    SPEED(55)    SPEED (44)      SPEED(33)    

    (10     20)          ?             ?
    (6      21.5)        ?             ?
    (0      22)          ?             ?
```

But I dont't  know how to get other values from another cordinates.
I haven't got any idea how link coordinates to speeds and depths and put it to columns.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to create a dictionary that maps each X coord to the list of tuples with that X coord:

```
>>> tupus = [ (1,0,1), (1,13,4), (2,11,2), (2,14,5) ]
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> tupudict = defaultdict( lambda: [] ) # default val for a key is empty list
>>> for tupu in tupus: tupudict[tupu[0]].append(tupu)
...
>>> tupudict[1]
[(1, 0, 1), (1, 13, 4)]
>>> tupudict[2]
[(2, 11, 2), (2, 14, 5)]
```

Then you process the dict key by key, or dump the values into a list of lists of tuples, or whatever.

Edited to add an answer to your comment about just splitting a list:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> mylist = [11,11,11,11,12,12,15,15,15,15,15,15,20,20,20]
>>> uniquedict = defaultdict( lambda: [] )
>>> for n in mylist: uniquedict[n].append(n)
...
>>> uniquedict
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x00000000033092E8>, {20: [20, 20, 20], 11: [11, 11, 11, 11], 12: [12, 12], 15: [15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15]})
>>> uniquedict[11]
[11, 11, 11, 11]
```

Note that, for every n in your input list, uniquedict[n] is now a list of all the n's from your input list.

Comment: If I understand you, I still think my idea will work just fine. But maybe I am misunderstanding what you are trying to do. Good luck!

Comment: This code wokrs perfectly. But i need little differnts thing. Because I have gor coordinates and they are dublicated. 55 ,55 ,55, 44 ,44 ,44, 33, 33, 33
For each coordinate I have columns with SPEED and DEPTHS.
So i think at first I should plit the list of coordinates and link it to depths and speed. Something like
№55  DEPTHS      Speed          
            (10,6,0)       20,21,22    
№44  DEPTHS      Speed          
            (10,5,0)       23,24,25   
№33  DEPTHS      Speed 
            (10,4,0)       26,27,28

Comment: I'm not following you. I thought that was exactly what my solution was doing. You understand that the (1,0,1) in my example is straight from your example. (Well, your original example. You've edited your question now.) Can you give me a small example, in Python syntax, showing exactly how the input looks and exactly how the output looks? Like this: Input is [1,2] and desired output is [2,1]. It's crucial that both the input and the output be in Python syntax.

Comment: Yeah, I know, this is to difficult to explain online. But If you could advice me how to write script to split list by uniq value I mean. > In: my_list =[11,11,11,11,12,12,15,15,15,15,15,15,20,20,20]  And there are 11-4,12-2,15-6,20-3 items. So in next list for exsample range(0:100) I have to split on 4,2,6,3 parts

Comment: You're still not giving me your exact input in Python syntax and your exact desired output in Python syntax. To answer your question about splitting a list by unique value, I edited my answer above. But be aware that you will very likely want to attach something to those integers, which is what my original answer, using tuples, was about.